# Add View to rootframe c#/xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

Is there a way to add a view to the rootframe in windows 8.1 c#/xaml, so my content changes (page Navigation) and the other view just stays there?

What I want to do is to add a advertisiemtn on the left side which will stay the whole navigation process and must not be reloaded/replaced on every page.

Is it possible over the App.xaml

Has anybody done this so far.

Any link/snippet would be helpfull.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you need to add an entire view? Or can you just add the content in a full-screen [Popup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br227842)?

Comment: Hmmm... should be a entire view, but I will give it a try. Thanks @Nate Diamond

Comment: The other option is to create a Frame within your current Frame. Then you can Navigate the sub-frame. This is how most of the Windows Store App Samples work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create root page, for example BasePage.xaml which will contain your ads and another frame, in which you can make all your navigation.

`<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
   //your ads here 
   <Frame x:Name="rootFrame"/>
</Grid>`

Please check out this tutorial: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj150604.aspx, where is described how to share appear between pages. You need the same thing, but you will share your ads block.